# How to write VBA for Do Until last row of data set

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and looking to run a code to colour cells in rows in a specific colour. I have been using DO UNTIL and always end with an extra cell coloured. What is the best way to overcome this.

The table I am working with looks like this,

1. Number/Name
2. 1/test_01
3. 2/test_02
4. 3/test_03
5. 4/test_04
6. 5/test_05

and continues on and the end will change each time i run the code.

I have set up a test sheet to get the basic idea running so I can expand upon it once I have it running properly. This specific test is dividing column A (Number) by 2 and if there is a remainder of 1 then it will be coloured one way and if not it will be coloured another.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim row_cnt As Integer
row_cnt = 1

Do Until Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & row_cnt).Value = ""
row_cnt = row_cnt + 1
        If Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & row_cnt).Value Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        Range("A" & row_cnt & ":B" & row_cnt).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Else
        Range("A" & row_cnt & ":B" & row_cnt).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I expect the cells to be coloured until the last cell with a value in. However, this code goes past that and colours an extra cell. I am looking for a way to improve what I have.

Comment: Just a note - this can be done with conditional formatting. Is VBA required? Also, the placement of `row_cnt = row_cnt + 1` at the beginning  is causing the extra cell to be colored. Increment `row_cnt` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically find the last row, such that:

```
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
row_cnt = 1
Do until row_cnt = lr+1 'so you get actions on your last row
    'do stuff
    row_cnt = row_cnt + 1
loop
```

if you can avoid vba for this, bigben's suggestion for conditional formatting would be solid

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific Q "Why doesn't my `Do Until`work":

It's because you test based on a value of `row_cnt` , then immediately increment it inside the loop, so process the next row.

To fix that, move the increment to just before `Loop` and adjust the initialisation of `row_cnt`

On a side note, you should use Long rather than Integer as the counter data type